# Convert sql binary (16) to utf-8 byte in .net

Tags: sql, .net, utf-8, binary, byte

I have values stored in a sql database with datatype of `binary(16)`, they come over into the .NET application (using Entity Framework) as type `System.Data.Linq.Binary`. I'd like to convert this binary representation of my data to data type byte[] without losing any data and preferably using UTF-8 encoding. Is this not built into the .NET framework? Must I convert it to some intermediary data type first before being able to get my byte array?

Answer (score 0):

Binary has *nothing* to do with UTF-8.

binary(16) means 16 bytes of binary data. There is a Binary::ToArray method to get a byte array.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.binary.toarray